# VNC remote desktop without asking permission prompt

Tags: 20.04, permissions, remote-desktop, vnc

I'm trying to access Ubuntu 22.04 remotely using VNC without having to accept the connection on the host machine each time. When I enable the default VNC screen sharing in Ubuntu 22.04 I always get the prompt on the host computer to allow the connection.

[image: prompt to allow sharing desktop]

When researching this issue I found instructions to enable sharing where there was a checkbox like in the image below.

[image: option to not ask for access]

My screen looks like this when I enable sharing

[image: no ask option]

I tried using dconf editor to see if I could find the option to not ask for remote connections, but I got the same options I had on the share setup screen.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to allow remoting into this machine without someone being on the machine to allow the connection?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I feel like such an idiot...worked on this for 2 days and then found the answer in front of me 36 minutes after I made this post.

Use dconf editor to change auth-method from 'prompt' to 'password'

[dconf image on setting change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFbBU.png)

I still don't know why this option isn't on the "Share" screen on the GUI. Would make more sense.